# Why do I need to put dictionary name with key in addtional brackets when I use cycle?

Tags: python

I have completed simple parsing learning task, but I can't understand why second cycle is working as it is and why it needs this additional brackets:

```
file_name = open('dummy-access.log')
lines = file_name.readlines()
file_name.close()
response_count = collections.Counter()
for line in lines:
    elements = line.split()
    response_count[elements[0]] += 1
    enter code here
average_count = []
for key in response_count:
    average_count += [response_count[key]]
print(round(sum(average_count) / len(average_count)))
```

If I change the last line to: `average_count += response_count[key]`, I get

`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: How does `response_count` look like?

Comment: Let's be clear here - do you want to add new values to the list `average_count`, or do you want to accumulate a sum value in `average_count`?

Comment: `response_count[key]` is an integer, so adding it to the list `average_count` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: A more idiomatic way of expressing that final line would be `average_count.append(response_count[key])`.

Comment: because list can only concatenate/add list to another list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `+=` on a list, it expects another list (or more generally, an iterable) as its left hand operand. With the square brackets, you create a list so you can append the integer. Usually, just use the `.append` method instead of `+=`, i.e. `average_count.append(response_count[key])`.

If I read what you want to do correctly, you want to take the average value of of a dictionary-like structure (`collections.Counter` included). If so, try using this:

```
response_count = collections.Counter(whatever)

average_count = sum(response_count.values()) / len(response_count)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't a list more specific than an iterable?

Comment: Thanks, yes. I have completed the task, but I didn't understood why it is working so. Now it's clear: += means that I need to put right type of variable there

Comment: @RickyKim Sorry, I mean *generally*.